# Lock resources to prevent unexpected changes

Tags: azure

I'm attempting to lock a folder in Azure to prevent anyone deleting it. I am setting the lock level to `CanNotDelete`. I'm wondering if I set this on the parent folder does the sub folders inherit this lock level so they too can not be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I set this on the parent folder does the sub folders
>   inherit this lock level so they too can not be deleted.

Let's say, we create a storage account in this resource group, apply `CanNotDelete` to this group, then we can't delete this storage account, but we can delete the blobs in this storage account.

By default, when you apply a lock at a parent scope, **all resources** within that scope inherit the same lock. Even resources you add later inherit the lock from the parent. The most restrictive lock in the inheritance takes precedence.

Resource Manager locks apply only to operations that happen in the management plane, which consists of operations sent to https://management.azure.com. **The locks do not restrict how resources perform their own functions.** Resource changes are restricted, but resource operations are not restricted.

For example, a ReadOnly lock on a SQL Database prevents you from deleting or modifying the database, but it does not prevent you from creating, updating, or deleting data in the database. Data transactions are permitted because those operations are not sent to https://management.azure.com.

More information about how locks are applied, please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources#how-locks-are-applied).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have an issue regrading the locks. I set a lock using the UI in Azure lock All resources --> select resource --> locks --> Add and set the lock to `Delete`. I then deleted a container inside the storage account and Azure did not prevent me from deleting the container. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if I need to make changes in the storage account template aswel?

Comment: @CraigGallagher Glad to answer your question.  the locks do not restrict how resources perform their own functions, for example, we create a storage account in this resource group, apply CanNotDelete to this group, then we can't delete this storage account, but we can delete the blobs or containers in this storage account. it is a by design behavior :) If you want other users can't delete your container, we can use [RBAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure) to manager your resource.

Comment: Hi I was looking at the document provided and it doesn't show how I can create a user to have read and write excess but not be able to delete a container. What I need to do is prevent a user from deleting a container however they can add and remove blobs from within this container.

Comment: @CraigGallagher As far as I know, we can't do that, because role reader can view everything, but can't make changes. they can't create container in your storage account.

Comment: So there is no way we can set some sort of rule to prevent a container being deleted but allows blobs inside that container be added or removed? If not is there something I can do similar to do this

Comment: @CraigGallagher we can create custom role, but I have not try that, I will test to create custom role to achieve that. I will give you update tomorrow:) about built-in riles, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles)

Comment: @CraigGallagher unfortunately, we can't use RBAC to limit user can add container but can't delete container :(  Maybe we should just grant reader promission, if they want to add container in storage account, ask admin to do it.